# Multiple Aliases triggering same function

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc, alias, functions

I'm trying to create a function, but I want to trigger by either aliases : `debugApp`, `debugApi`

Rather than creating 2 functions to do the same thing

```
debugApp() {

    #update .env to generate log
    sed -i -e 's/.*API_DEBUG=.*/API_DEBUG=true/g' /Users/jdoe/laravel/.env
    echo "-----------------------"
    cat /Users/jdoe/laravel/.env | grep API_DEBUG


    #remove old logs
    # rm -rf /Users/jdoe/laravel/storage/logs/*
    ls /Users/jdoe/laravel/storage/logs/

    #display correct logs
    tail -f /Users/jdoe/laravel/storage/logs/laravel-$(date "+%Y-%m-*").log
}


debugApi() {

    #update .env to generate log
    sed -i -e 's/.*API_DEBUG=.*/API_DEBUG=true/g' /Users/jdoe/laravel/.env
    echo "-----------------------"
    cat /Users/jdoe/laravel/.env | grep API_DEBUG


    #remove old logs
    # rm -rf /Users/jdoe/laravel/storage/logs/*
    ls /Users/jdoe/laravel/storage/logs/

    #display correct logs
    tail -f /Users/jdoe/laravel/storage/logs/laravel-$(date "+%Y-%m-*").log
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: I know that I can just do this `alias debugApp=debugApi`, but I'm wondering if there is another way.

Comment: What about `debugApi() { debugApp; }`?

Comment: @Cyrus that looks more like an answer than a comment! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this to get it to work

> alias debugApp=debugApi